# Can Magisk rules be enabled from Recovery (TWRP)?

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, magisk

Is it possible to configure Magisk by ADBing in through TWRP when you install it, so you can get it working on an initial install. I'm having problems with a splash screen -- my boot just locks at that process. I would like to see what's going on. I know Magisk provides LiveBoot would be a good fit, I can install in TWRP. But then I have to boot into Android to configure it to disable the boot screen (which I can not do).

From the [buildlog of Magisk V13,](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/6mhk98/magisk_v131_stable_released/dk1me3r/)

> [magiskpolicy] Updated rules for Android O, and Liveboot support

I can't figure out how enable those rules outside of a working boot?

Comment: If your just after the bootloop info. You can get adb logs of a bootloop sometimes even at the splash screen. Try to get them and post them so we can read them. Linux command: `adb logcat -v long > ~/Desktop/logcat.txt` windows command:
`adb logcat -v long > %userprofile%\desktop\logcat.txt` these logs can also be helpful linux: `adb logcat *:W *:S > ~/Desktop/logcatALLwarnings.txt` windows:
`adb logcat *:W *:S > %userprofile%\desktop\logcat.txt`

Comment: I was unable to adb anything it was dieing before that. I filed a regression with LineageOS though since I'm 100% sure now it's a build problem and the previous build works fine. This is also a new install  https://jira.lineageos.org/browse/REGRESSION-2222

Comment: If I don't get it wrong, you want to take boot log at boot when your device is stuck at SPLASH SCREEN? By splash screen you mean boot animation or the one we see initially at power on? Did you try Android SDK's "Monitor" tool for logcat? Or the "insecure" adb which enables to take "adb logcat" as soon as the logcatd starts on phone? Another option is to add a service to init.rc which saves logcat to a file which can later be accessed from TWRP on reboot. If your boot process doesn't get that far, consider getting kernel/init log through "dmesg" with high verbosity.